# How can i did not pass specific relationship with the cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

with the bus Station problem, how can i did not pass same station with the Cypher eg not any Node? or the relationship

```
                   StationF--StationG
                       |         |
StationA--StationB--StationC--StationD--StationE
                       |         |
                        Station H
```

for example, I want not to pass the StationC-StationH And 
StationH-StasionD

```
match(a:StationA)-[r:Road]-(z:StationE)
not any (node in nodes(p) | node.station) = StationH
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find the shortest path between `a` and `z`, you can use the [shortestpath](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path) function.

For example:

```
MATCH (a:StationA), (z:StationE), p = shortestPath((a)-[:Road*]-(z))
RETURN p
```